# Spring Security: How to get the login-page from the <sec:form-login> Tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I'm trying to get the *login-page* value from the `<sec:form-login>` that can be set in the *application-context.xml*:

```
<beans>
...
<sec:form-login login-page="/login.html" 
    authentication-failure-url="/failed.html"
    default-target-url="/secure/index.jsp" />
...
</beans>
```

E.g. I've got a *KerberosFailureHandler* which implements the *AuthenticationFailureHandler* Interface. This handler should redirect to the loginpage that is configured in my application-context.xml. But I don't know how to get the parameter. Is it possible to inject the value with an @Autowired or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the normal way to do that would be to extract the login page value to an external configuration (e.g. properties file, but it could be in .java just as well, especially if you use `@Configuration`). Then inject the same value into the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and the login configuration.

Comment: I followed your advice and put the parameter into a properties file that is a _<context:property-placeholder>_ in my Spring configuration file. I can extract the value in my _KerberosFailureHandler_ with the annotation _@Value("${key.in.properties.file}")_. Thanks!